# How to solve this wave equation in a triangle?

Tags: wave-equation

I want to solve the following problem.

We have a triangle with side lengths $a,b,c$.

We have a potential inside the triangle satisfying the 2D wave equation with source at $(x_0,y_0)$ which is $\partial^2_x \phi(x,y)+ \partial^2_y \phi(x,y) = \delta(x-x_0,y-y_0)$.

With boundary conditions that $\phi(x,y)=0$ on the boundary of the triangle.

Is there a solution to this basic problem somewhere in the literature?

I have a feeling it should be solved using elliptic functions.(At least I think this is true for special cases such as when the triangle is equilateral).

Comment: For an *arbitrary* triangle, this does *not* seem like a basic problem: there is no symmetry to exploit. Perhaps you could try finding a conformal map from the arbitrary triangle to an equilateral or right isosceles triangle, where the problem is tractable

Comment: What I mean is the problem is "basic". The solution may not be.